# Markov Inequality question.

Tags: probability

Markov Inequality:

There is, on average, $2$ million dollars worth of silver in stock over past 10 years. In that time frame, silver price has not gone above 5 dollars/lb and there cannot be more than $\frac{1}{2}$-million pounds because of space restrictions. How likely is it that 5 years ago there was less than 1 million dollars worth of silver in stock?

I'm trying to solve this Markov Inequality problem. However, I cannot figure out the expectation of X.

$$P( X \geq 1,000,000) \leq \frac{E(X)}{1,000,000}$$

What would E(X) be in this situation? I don't think it would be 2 million.

Comment: Well, the maximum value (2.5 million) is just over the average value (2 million), so pretty unlikely. Why is the denominator 1,000,000? $E(X)$ is indeed the expected value of silver - 2 million by supposition. A probability of 2 doesnt make sense

Comment: The denominator is 1,000,000 because that's the definition of Markov inequality i think? Why is the expected value of silver 2 million? Do we need to account for the space restrictions at all and the fact thats its over the past 5 years and not 10 years?